# How can I retrieve more data from Prestashop API to my flutter app?

Tags: android, api, flutter, mobile, prestashop

I looking for documentation about Prestashop API without success.
I am developing a mobile app with flutter which retrieve data from Prestashop API, the problem is I just can do a couple calls to the api as: list products, list clients, show misc info, etc...

I would like to be able to create a new order, add products to cart, create cart, etc... But I can't find any other solutions.

Should I create my own custom api service?

Edit:
This is the data already have

```
http://example.com/prestashop/api/products
http://example.com/prestashop/api/images
http://example.com/prestashop/api/customers
```

And I would like to get the and create the next one (i.e):

```
http://example.com/prestashop/api/cart/create
http://example.com/prestashop/api/cart/add_product/?id=number
http://example.com/prestashop/api/product/create
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

The lines of documentation you need are here:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/getting-started/#create-a-resource

#### How to create a new order via Prestashop API?

This process is called *create a resource*. So, if you want to create a new **order**, just:

1. Take all the same XML (or JSON) schema you see in http://example.com/prestashop/api/orders?schema=blank (add "&output_format=JSON" for JSON),
2. Fill it with your values (with no "id") and send with **POST** HTTP request back to http://example.com/prestashop/api/orders/

#### How to edit an order via Prestashop API?

This process is called *update a resource*. So, if you want to edit an **order ID 1**, just:

1. Take all the same XML (or JSON) schema you see in http://example.com/prestashop/api/orders/1 (add "&output_format=JSON" for JSON),
2. Fill it with your values and send with **PUT** HTTP request back to http://example.com/prestashop/api/orders/1

The same process is for all entities you see in `Prestashop back office > Advanced parameters > Webservice`.

*Note*: Please check if API is enabled and all check boxes are checked for the entity permissions you need. You can find it in `Prestashop back office > Advanced parameters > Webservice`.

[image: Prestashop Webservice permissions]

Comment: Do I need to create a customer before create order? Or I am able to create order with "anonymous" customer. Thank you

Comment: @Jotadrive Yes, you need to create a customer before create order. 'id_customer' is required for order. But a fresh Prestashop 1.7 installation usually has two dummy customers already created ('id_customer' 1 and 2), you can use these.

Comment: Ok @Indré I wanted to create anonymous orders or "Guest" orders, just for people who doesn't want to create an account.

Comment: @Jotadrive You need to look into your task from a totally different angle ;) Just "Enable guest checkout". More is here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Orders+preferences

Comment: @Indré I know that post, but previously you said I would need to create a customer before create order, because it is required. Isn't it?

Comment: @Jotadrive Yes, it is true. You need to create a "customer" before create an order. When a person is ordering as a "guest" he still is creating a "customer" (but without password) – in Prestashop terms he becomes a "customer" with "guest group" access. Because he still needs to enter his *email* address. *Email* address is obligatory. 
Guest checkout is shorter, but still it is with an email address. I guess all customers wants to get notified about their purchases somehow, so this is not a problem ;)